# Using Python curses colors, I don't understand what is wrong with my code

Tags: python, colors, curses

I want to use Python curses library to make the fisrt draft to a new app. I have the basics of curses, but don't know why the example below writes the text in gray instead of red :

```
import curses
from curses import wrapper
from time import sleep

def main(stdscr):
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    curses.start_color()
    stdscr.keypad(True)
    stdscr.addstr(10,10,"This text should be red",curses.COLOR_RED)
    stdscr.refresh()
    sleep(2)
    curses.nocbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(False)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()

wrapper(main)
```

I know I shouldn't rewrite the initialization steps after using "wrapper", but that's not the issue, I think, the text is still gray without it. I run this app in an xterm window, "has_colors" tells me the term is color capable (which I know because "ls" is colorfull).

If anyone could explain to me what I am doing wrong, I would be delighted :-P

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using a theme that remaps your colors?

Comment: Not that I am aware of...

Comment: I wish I had a MWE that I could run to test what I can expect... But couldn't find anything easy to use...

Comment: I wrote this https://github.com/thebjorn/doscmd-screen/ a while ago, check the test_screen.py file in the root folder...

Comment: Your code is not what I would call easy to read... Sorry, I know you want to help, but I need way more basic example :-)

Comment: Anyway, your basic example produces a colored "left bottom" on my screen, so it means I can write colored text...

Answer (score 1):

The attribute should use a *color pair*, not a *color number*.  You would make a color pair using [`init_pair`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.init_pair), use it via [`color_pair`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.color_pair)

For example

```
import curses
from curses import wrapper
from time import sleep

def main(stdscr):
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    curses.start_color()
    stdscr.keypad(True)
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLUE)
    stdscr.addstr(10,10,"This text should be red",curses.color_pair(1))
    stdscr.refresh()
    sleep(2)
    curses.nocbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(False)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()

wrapper(main)
```

Comment: I found another problem, which I haven't checked yet in the documentation : I wanted to use curses.addch with a color attribute : it doesn't work. Using addstr works. No problem, I can use addstr to insert one char strings ;-)

Comment: It "should" work according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.addch).  You might want to ask a new question for that.